# Store and Retrieve Data Between Blazor Client and Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Im trying to store data in either blazor server or blazor client. I would then need to retrieve that data in server and client. An example would be that I create some string data on the client side. I would like to read that data from the server side on blazor. Once I have read that data on the server side, I would like to change it and then read it back on the client side. I have tried using query, sessions, Request, Response, global variables and so on but nothing can be transferred between Blazor Client and Blazor Server. Please if you got it working can you post an example. I only need very little data to be stored. Im only manipulating a string. I dont need any authentication as my data is not valuable or needs to be private. So the easiest example would be the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new Blazor app and select Blazor WebAssembly App, if you then check the ASP.net Core hosted checkbox. The application will be created with a web API project.

This enables the web client to connect to the server side using HTTP to get or post information which can be as simple as a string or a complex object.

Example method which would be in the web API controller:

```cs
[HttpGet("{argument}")]
public string Get(string argument)
{
    return $"The argument received was {argument}";
}
```

Example client code calling the Web API:

```cs
string Result { get; set; }
string argument = "what is the weather?";

async Task CallWebApi()
{
    Result = await Http.GetStringAsync($"WeatherForecast/{argument}");
}
```

[Example solution in github](https://github.com/Mark-Phillipson/WebApiDemo)